# Invoking an Action - determine if the instance it belongs to is null

Tags: c#, .net, delegates

I have a method that takes an Action as a parameter.  Actions are stored in a queue and executed when particular resources become available.  Before I invoke an Action, I'd like to check if the instance it is a member of is null.

I did a simple test with the following stupid example.  The Action invoked successfully after setting the invokee to null, and as expected, I got a NullReferenceException when attempting to access the property on the null invokee.  Nothing jumped out at me when examining the Action at runtime that suggested I could determine if its instance was null.

I guess I could pass in the Action and the instance as parameters and test if the instance is null before invoking.  Is it possible to test for a null invokee, or is this just a case of bad design on my part?

**UPDATE:**

I added the line,

**if (explosion.Target != null)**

to Bazooka.Fire(), to check for a null target, but it is still invoking the delegate in my example.

```
public void LetsDoThis()
    {
        var bazooka = new Bazooka();
        var rocketLauncher = new RocketLauncher();

        bazooka.LockAndLoad(rocketLauncher.BlowStuffUp);

        rocketLauncher = null;

        bazooka.Fire();

        bool wasThisCompletelyAwesome = rocketLauncher.ThisIsAwesome;
    }

public class RocketLauncher
    {
        public void BlowStuffUp()
        {
            bool stuffIsBlowingUp = true;
        }

        public bool ThisIsAwesome
        {
            get
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

public class Bazooka
    {
        private List<Action> explosions = new List<Action>();

        public void LockAndLoad(Action loadIt)
        {
            this.explosions.Add(loadIt);
        }

        public void Fire()
        {
            foreach (Action explosion in explosions)
                if (explosion.Target != null)
                    explosion.Invoke();
        }
    }
```

Comment: What are you actually trying to solve? Meaning, take a step back and describe the overall problem you need solved (possibly in a different question here on SO).

Comment: I feel like what I described is a generic pattern that can be used for several problems.  If there is a defect in the pattern itself, we can discuss that.  For my particular purposes, I am using it for a browser pool that takes requests for browsers (as Actions), and invokes the Actions when a browser becomes available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This won't work.

The `Action` does not in any way care about the original reference *variable* you got it from, it makes a copy of the reference *value*, and thus has its own reference.

Note that this also means that as long as you still have a reference to the delegate, even though you have no other references to the original object, it will still not be eligible for garbage collection.

The `.Target` property refers to the instance on which the method that the delegate refers to should be invoked, basically the `this` "parameter" to that method.

Thus, to have a `null` target you need to get the delegate from a static method, try this in [LINQPad](http://linqpad.net):

```
void Main()
{
    Action a = Static.StaticMethod;
    (a.Target == null).Dump();
}

public static class Static
{
    public static void StaticMethod() { }
}
```

You can see that the delegate carries its own instance with this [LINQPad](http://linqpad.net) code:

```
void Main()
{
    Dummy d = new Dummy { Name = "A" };
    Action a = d.Method;

    d = new Dummy { Name = "B" };
    Action b = d.Method;

    d = null;

    a();
    b();
}

public class Dummy
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public void Method()
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Name=" + Name);
    }
}
```

The output here will be

```
Name=A
Name=B
```

---

As requested, let me clarify the difference between the *instance*, the *reference*, and the *variable*.

When you construct an object instance, like this:

```
var rocketLauncher = new RocketLauncher();
```

What you're doing is calling a method known as a constructor. The return value from this constructor is a reference to the newly constructed object. Basically, it's a pointer, meaning a memory address of where in the memory that object now lives. If it makes it easier to understand the rest of this answer you can consider it to be just a number.

Additionally you declared a variable, `rocketLauncher`, to hold this reference, this number.

Note that the object is separate from the variable, they're two distinct items. In one place in memory you have an object, in another place you have the variable containing the reference to that object, it's address, that number.

So when you do this:

```
bazooka.LockAndLoad(rocketLauncher.BlowStuffUp);
```

Let's simplify it a bit:

```
Action a = rocketLauncher.BlowStuffUp;
// bazooka.LockAndLoad(a);
```

let's forget about the part where we call that LockAndLoad method, and look at what happened when we "converted" the method `BlowStuffUp` into a delegate of type `Action`.

Basically, two things was "grabbed":

- Which method to make the delegate refer to
- The object instance on which to call that method

You can liken this to the following code:

```
MethodReference = rocketLauncher.BlowStuffUp;
object target = rocketLauncher;
// wrap this into a delegate
```

This now means you have *two* references to that object, one lives in the `rocketLauncher` variable, the other now lives inside the delegate.

What you do with that *variable* does not in any way change the value of that delegate, it still points to the same object as before. Basically it made a copy of that number. That number is still sitting there inside the delegate.

This is pretty much exactly the same as this:

```
int a = 10;
int b = a;
a = 0;
// b is still 10
```

So, to conclude, the `.Target` property of the delegate does not in any way know, or care, about the original *variable* that you got the delegate from. A copy was made of the reference value from that original variable, into the delegate, and what you do with the variable afterwards makes no difference at all.

So basically:

- The *instance* is the object, it lives somewhere in memory
- The *reference* is basically the address to it, and you can look at it as sort of a number
- The *variable* is one place where you can store that reference

---

Now, what if you *really* want to make the delegate depend on the variable, and care about the value it now has, when you get around to calling it?

Well, one way would be to do this:

```
bazooka.LockAndLoad(delegate
{
    if (rocketLauncher != null)
        rocketLauncher.BlowStuffUp();
});
```

This would make an anonymous method, that would capture the variable itself, and then inside that anonymous method you could explicitly check what value the variable has at the time you call the delegate. If this part, about an anonymous method, does not make sense, you should ask another question here (ideally after reading a bit about anonymous methods, captured variables, and looked over some of the existing questions here on SO).

To test out an anonymous method, test the following code in [LINQPad](http://linqpad.net):

```
void Main()
{
    object dummy = new object();
    Action a = delegate
    {
        if (dummy != null)
            Debug.WriteLine("not null");
        else
            Debug.WriteLine("null");
    };

    a();
    dummy = null;
    a();
}
```

It will print out:

```
not null
null
```

Comment: If the delegate doesn't reference the original instance, what causes the obstacle to the original being garbage collected?

Comment: It *does* refer to the instance. It just doesn't care about the *variable*.

Comment: As an aside (NOT A SOLUTION), the only way I can think of to make it care about the variable itself would be to create your action using bazooka.LockAndLoad(() => rocketLauncher.BlowStuffUp()); instead - that way the closure would capture a ref to the rocketLauncher variable itself, and then you would get a NullReferenceException if you invoked the stored action after the line rocketLauncher = null; To find out that the variable was null before invoking would be trickier. You'd probably have to reflect into the Target property (you can certainly see that it's null in the debugger).

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Thanks for the detailed explanation.  I understand your original point now.

Comment: Basically, the root of the problem is the confusion, as is evident in your question title, "if the instance it belongs to is null". If the instance was alive at the time you grabbed the delegate, it will be alive when you call it, because the instance can not be null. The *reference* to it (the original one that is) can be however, but that makes no difference.

Comment: Yep, I see what you're saying.  Ultimately, what I'd like to accomplish is have a class that queues delegates to invoke, but does not keep the object they reference from being garbage collected.  Would using a WeakReference be a good idea for that?

Comment: Using  `WeakReference` or `WeakDelegate` would only handle the garbage collector "problem". There is no guarantee that GC will have run immediately after you setting some variables to `null`. I would find a different way of solving what you need solved.

Comment: I don't need it to happen immediately and I don't expect that since collection is non-deterministic, but I don't want the invoker class to be an obstacle if all other references to those objects are null...

Comment: Then you need to use one of the `Weak*` types, yes. Look at `WeakDelegate` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc533276.aspx).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41767/discussion-between-dustmouse-and-lasse-v-karlsen)

Answer (score 3):

Use the `Target` property to check:

```
if(yourAction.Target != null) {
  //...
}
```

Any `Delegate` type has a property called `Target`, so you can also use this for other types of delegate.

**Update**: In fact, when you use your `Action` to wrap some method of an object, that object won't never be disposed and that means the `NullReferenceException` can't be thrown in that case **Unless** you wrap another method **of another object** and this method has something to do with the null object.

Comment: I updated my original post.  For some reason, it is still invoking the action in my sample code, even after I added that line.

Comment: @dustmouse you should make your problem clearer, see my update for my understanding about your problem, in fact the object you try setting to null does not have any method wrapped by your Action.

Comment: The NullReferenceException is what I observed from executing the code.  It sounds like you're saying it couldn't throw that exception.  I apologize if I misconstrued your meaning.

Comment: @dustmouse I can see you try setting `rocketLauncher = null;` before invoking the action and yes in that case it should not throw exception, because I've tried the same example. When your Action keeps a reference to the method of `rocketLauncher`, it can't be disposed. In fact in some cases, this is considered as **memory leakage** and we even have to implement some **weak event** pattern to avoid it.

Comment: Okay, I'm not sure why we are getting different results from executing the same code.  But I hear you on the memory leak issue.

Answer (score 0):

Well, not in any way trying to argue with Lasse's rather detailed response, I would like to throw in my 5 cents on this.

When you invoke the LockAndLoad method of the bazooka class you simply add the method that's passed to the method to the List explosions collection of the bazooka class. Nulling the instantiation of the class whose method you had passed to the LockAndLoad method (in your example 'rocketLauncher') has NO effect on that collection, meaning that the Target property of the specific Action will not become null. You would have to explicitly remove the method from that collection BEFORE nulling the instantiation of the class.

```
bazooka.Unload(rocketLauncher.BlowStuffUp);
rocketLauncher = null;
```

Of course this works only if you modified your bazooka class to the following method in your bazooka class:

```
public void Unload(Action unloadIt)
{
    if (explosions.Contains(unloadIt))
        explosions.Remove(unloadIt);
}
```

This may not be what you are hoping for, but I hope it helped anyhow.